# How to delete all nodes of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a code to delete all nodes of a BST (each node has only three attributes, left, right and data, there are no parent pointers). The following code is what I have come up with, it deletes only the right half of the tree, keeping the left half intact. How do I modify it so that the left half is deleted as well (so that ultimately I am left with only the root node which has neither left or right subtrees)?

```
def delete(root):
    global last
    if root:
     delete(root.left)
     delete(root.right)
     if not (root.left or root.right):
        last = root
     elif root.left == last:
        root.left = None
     else:
        root.right = None
```

And secondly, can anybody suggest an iterative approach as well, using stack or other related data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blckknght is right about garbage collection, but in case you want to do some more complex cleanup than your example suggests or understand why your code didn't work, i'll provide an additional answer:

Your problem seems to be the `elif node.left == last` check.

I'm not sure what your `last` variable is used for or what the logic is behind it.
But the problem is that `node.left` is almost never equal to `last` (you only assign a node to the `last` variable if both children are already set to `None`, which they aren't for any of the interesting nodes (those that have children)).

If you look at your code, you'll see that in that if `node.left` isn't equal to `last` only the right child gets set to `None`, and thus only the right part of the subtree is deleted.

I don't know python, but this should work:

```
def delete(node):
    if node:

        # recurse: visit all nodes in the two subtrees
        delete(node.left)           
        delete(node.right)

        # after both subtrees have been visited, set pointers of this node to None
        node.left = None
        node.right = None
```

(I took the liberty of renaming your `root` parameter to `node`, since the node given to the function doesn't have to be the root-node of the tree.)

Comment: That was neat! Thanks! Can you provide an iterative approach as well? And this process cleans up the left and right subtrees, but doesn't set the `root` to `None`. So I guess you will have to do it after the function returns.

Comment: Glad i could be of help! This was my first post on stackoverflow and it feels good answering questions :)

Anyway, i actually don't know python at all, so i don't know how to do the iterative approach in python. But you're right that you can use a stack datastructure to do it iteratively. Maybe googling for "iterative tree traversal" will give some hits (the wikipedia page for example).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete both subtrees, there's no need to recurse. Just set `root.left` and `root.right` to `None` and let the garbage collector take care of them. Indeed, rather than making a `delete` function in the first place, you could just set `root = None` and be done with it!

**Edit:** If you need to run cleanup code on the data values, you might want to recurse through the tree to get to all of them if the GC doesn't do enough. Tearing down the links in the tree shouldn't really be necessary, but I'll do that too for good measure:

```
def delete(node):
    if node:
        node.data.cleanup() # run data value cleanup code

        delete(node.left)   # recurse
        delete(node.right)

        node.data = None    # clear pointers (not really necessary)
        node.left = None
        none.right = None
```

You had also asked about an iterative approach to traversing the tree, which is a little more complicated. Here's a way to an traversal using a `deque` (as a stack) to keep track of the ancestors:

```
from collections import deque

def delete_iterative(node):
    stack = deque()
    last = None

    # start up by pushing nodes to the stack until reaching leftmost node
    while node:
        stack.append(node)
        node = node.left

    # the main loop
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()

        # should we expand the right subtree?
        if node.right && node.right != last: # yes
            stack.append(node)
            node = node.right

            while node: # expand to find leftmost node in right subtree
                stack.append(node)
                node = node.left

        else: # no, we just came from there (or it doesn't exist)
            # delete node's contents
            node.data.cleanup()

            node.data = None # clear pointers (not really necessary)
            node.left = None
            node.right = None

            # let our parent know that it was us it just visited
            last = node
```

Comment: Yeah, that's possible of course, but it's an interview question, where the task is to delete the nodes one by one bottom up.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for that is if the data values have some special cleanup logic that needs to be run on them. I'll update my answer to handle this, though it will end up being a lot like @Bjarke's!

Comment: @Cupidvogel, I've updated with a recursive and an iterative version. The iterative version is much more complicated, but I hope I've added enough comments to make it comprehensible. Again, if there's no special cleanup work needed on the data, simply doing `root=None` will be best!

Comment: Does the `append` method add the node to the beginning of the stack? What about the `pop`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel The `deque` class's `append` and `pop` methods both work on the end of the sequence (which I'm treating as the "top" of the stack). It also has `append_left` and `pop_left` methods for working on the start, so it's fairly arbitrary which end to use. I'm used to using `append` though with `list`s, so that's what I stuck with. You could even use a `list` to implement the stack, but its performance won't be as good as a `deque` (though it should be [asymptotically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) the same).

Comment: Exactly. Since you are appending and popping off the end, a normal stack would do, right? Why use a dequeue?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "a normal stack". A `list`? Like I said, a `deque` has somewhat better performance than a list for `append` and `pop`. In a rough test I just did with the `timeit` module, it appears to be about twice as fast.

Comment: No no, I didn't mean a list implementation. I meant a linked-list implementation, where `push` an `pop` both operates on the end of the stack, whereas in dequeue, both can work on either end of the stack. So in this case, won't a stack suffice?

Comment: Oh, sure, you could do your own stack. But `deque` is already written for you in C and it's in the standard library. I think it's implemented as a doubly linked list (or perhaps a doubly linked list of array segments). It's almost certainly going to be faster than anything you could write in pure Python. Using a `list` would probably be faster too.

Answer (score 2):

An iterative post-order traversal using a stack could look like this:

```
def is_first_visit(cur, prev):
    return prev is None or prev.left is cur or prev.right is cur

def visit_tree(root):
    if root:
        todo = [root]
        previous = None
        while len(todo):
            node = todo[-1]
            if is_first_visit(node, previous):
                # add one of our children to the stack
                if node.left: 
                    todo.append(node.left)
                elif node.right:
                    todo.append(node.right)
                # now set previous to ourself and continue
            elif previous is node.left:
                # we've done the left subtree, do right subtree if any
                if node.right:
                    todo.append(node.right)
            else: 
                # previous is either node.right (we've visited both sub-trees)
                # or ourself (we don't have a right subtree)
                do_something(node)
                todo.pop()
            previous = node
```

`do_something` does whatever you want to call "actually deleting this node".

You can do it a bit more simply by setting an attribute on each node to say whether it has had `do_something` called on it yet, but obviously that doesn't work so well if your nodes have `__slots__` or whatever, and you don't want to modify the node type to allow for the flag.

Comment: That looks promising. Can you add a few more comments to your code so that I can understand it properly?

Comment: In Python, there's no `free` function like in C to deallocate a node. So how can `do_something` delete a node by itself?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: not my problem ;-) The task you've been set, "delete all nodes of a BST" is kind of nonsensical in Python, because in Python you can't explicitly delete an object. `def do_something(node): node.right = node.left = None` might be what you want.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was trying to do in my code, by setting a flag to the last visited node. Then coming to the parent node, checking whether the last visited node is the current node's left or right subtree, and deleting that part accordingly. In the bottom-up approach, the deletion will start from bottom, so we will never have to delete a subtree with more than one element.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you just want to set the left and right nodes to `None` you could not bother with `do_something` at all. Instead, in the `elif previous is node.left` clause set `node.left = None` and in the `else` clause set `node.right = None`. That way you'd set the left-node to `None` *before* processing the right subtree, which maybe is more in the spirit of what you're aiming for. Makes no practical difference other than affecting the order in which the Python runtime can reclaim the nodes (assuming there are no references to them from outside the tree).

Comment: Thanks. I accepted Bjarke's answer, since he is a newbie, and this might encourage him.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with those conditions after the recursive calls, but I think this should be enough:

```
def delete(root):
  if root:
    delete(root.left)
    delete(root.right)

    root = None
```

As pointed out in comments, Python does not pass parameters by reference. In that case you can make this work in Python like this:

```
def delete(root):
  if root:
    delete(root.left)
    delete(root.right)

    root.left = None
    root.right = None

Usage:
delete(root)
root = None
```

As for an iterative approach, you can try this. It's pseudocode, I don't know python. Basically we do a BF search.

```
delete(root):
  make an empty queue Q
  Q.push(root)
  while not Q.empty:
    c = Q.popFront()
    Q.push(c.left, c.right)
    c = None
```

Again, this won't modify the root by default if you use it as a function, but it will delete all other nodes. You could just set the root to None after the function call, or remove the parameter and work on a global root variable.

Comment: Setting `root`, which is an argument to the function (and so a local variable) to `None` will do nothing useful.

Comment: @Blckknght - I don't know how python arguments work, but the logic is correct. You recursively delete the subtrees and then the root. If it's not passed by reference you can just set the children to None and the root separately outside the main function, or just pass `root` by reference.

Comment: @Cupidvogel - probably because of what Blckknght said. You need to either pass `root` by reference or replace `root = None` with `root.left = root.right = None` and after the initial function call set `root = None`.

Comment: @Cupidvogel - I posted an iterative approach.

Comment: Well, it does the trick, but not bottom-up, rather top-down. The moment you delete the root, you don't need to delete the left or right subtrees, since they won't be accessible anyway. What I want is to delete the leaves first, then their parents, blah blah blah, until only the root is left.

Comment: @Cupidvogel - in that case Steve's answer should do the trick. If this is an interview question though, I'm guessing they assume there is no GC to clean up after you. So once you delete the root, the subtrees won't be accessible anymore, but they will take up memory. This is still useful in those cases.

Comment: "If this is an interview question though, I'm guessing they assume there is no GC to clean up after you" - you might be right. But Python guarantees GC, so if the interview assumes otherwise it's a strange interview. CPython implements GC as reference-counting plus "automatic" (I assume mark-sweep-based) collection. You can disable the latter but not the former, and a tree by definition doesn't contain reference cycles. So unless you want to actually *do* something at each node this really is a pointless activity.

Comment: @SteveJessop - when I said it might be an interview question, I assumed a language-agnostic one or a C one, and that the OP just chose to implement it in python because that's his preference. If it's a question for a language with a GC, not accepting the `root = null` answer is indeed silly.